# What does ':' colon do in JavaScript's import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, adonis.js

Given the example below.

```js
import { QueryClientContract, TransactionClientContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Database'
```

The use of the colon has confused me and never understood where the imported files could be referenced from.

Comment: It's not part of JavaScript; it's something relevant for whatever module "bundler" you're using. JavaScript just says that the `from` value has to be a string constant; it says nothing about the semantics of the string contents.

Comment: And do you have idea of which bundler could be able to translate that?  And what does that mean for the bundler?

Comment: not 100% familar with `adonis.js`, but I suspect it has something to do with scoped packages <https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes>. Some tooling might have installed the packages as scoped packages, and node (I am assuming node?) can resolve the package.

Comment: I don't recognize that, sorry. Where did you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript, the `:` colon is used as a type annotation syntax to specify the type of a variable, parameter, or return value. However, in the context you provided, `':'` is not specifically related to type annotations. It is used in the AdonisJS framework to define a declaration merging syntax.

In AdonisJS, the declaration `declare module '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'` is used to extend or augment the existing types or interfaces defined in the `@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route` module.

For example, you might have a custom route macro that you want to add to the existing `Route` module. By using the `declare module` syntax, you can add your custom methods or properties to the `Route` module, making them available for use throughout your application.

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```js
declare module '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route' {
  interface RouteContract {
    myCustomMethod: () => void;
  }
}
```

In the above code, we are declaring that the `RouteContract` interface in the `@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route` module should include a new method called `myCustomMethod`.

This syntax allows you to extend or modify the existing types or interfaces provided by AdonisJS or other libraries, enabling you to add your own custom functionality.

I hope this clarifies the usage of `':'` in the AdonisJS declaration merging syntax. Let me know if you have any further questions!

Answer (score 3):

Prefixes for modules have existed for a while, though until recently they didn't affect the module functionality at all (you can read more about this development [here](https://stateful.com/blog/node-18-prefix-only-modules)). It looks like this specific prefix on these modules was supplied by the installation process for `Adonis.js` and given that the toolkit uses custom commands for things like building production versions of your project, it *may* have some custom processes for e.g. loading minimised versions of a dependency specifically for production builds.

There is not currently a standardised meaning or effect of using a prefix like this, outside of `node:` (which restricts imports to core packages and prevents you from accidentally downloading a malicious package by mistake, due to a typo). Some projects use this for internal purposes and it will depend on the specific project what effects the prefix may or may not have.

Answer (score -6):

**In import statement you are importing ambient module. I recommend you to read following documentation for more details.**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules

Comment: Oooops! Maybe the referenced doc still made me understood nothing about it.